# Describing GeoPandas dependency in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am developing a Python package based on my GeoPandas data processing logic.
I am using Elementary OS 5 and Python 3.8.

I created an empty `requirements.txt` file on my project root, and added `geopandas` in it.

```
# requirements.txt
geopandas
```

Next, I created a new virtual environment with `python3.8 -m venv myenv` and activated it.
But when I tried to install geopandas using `pip` command, I got the following error

```
(myenv) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
...
Collecting pyproj>=2.2.0 (from geopandas->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/12/7a8cca32506747c05ffd5c6ba556cf8435754af0939906cbcc7fa5802ea3/pyproj-3.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Cython.Build.cythonize not found. Cython is required to build pyproj.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-u6x_qwoi/pyproj/
(myenv) $
```

I searched for a while but most of answers I tried didn't help because I was stuck on setting up `pyproj`.

How can I solve this issue correctly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you do not need the recent version of GeoPandas, you can use GeoPandas < 0.7.

Here's a sample `requirements.txt` file.

```
pyproj==1.9.6
geopandas==0.6.3
```

I tried several versions of `pyproj`, but 1.9.6 was the easiest version to install on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.
Note that `pyproj==1.9.6` dependency must be before the `geopandas` line.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it and let you know the resutl.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this as geopandas 0.6.3 is old.

Comment: This answer worked. And all my GeoPandas scripts worked well with version 0.6.3.
Thank you again, @HotteShen

Answer (score -1):

As the error message says, `Cython is required to build pyproj.`. You need to install Cython to successfully pip install pyproj.

```
pip install Cython
```

However, note that pip installing geopandas and its dependencies is generally not recommended and you should prefer conda if possible.

Comment: This is not a solution. First of all, installing Cython doesn't simply help installing `pyproj` on Linux environment. And if Cython is needed, it should be added as a build dependency in `pyproject.toml` as PEP518.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But unfortunately, I faced to many more issues after installing Cython. Could you explain for more detailed instructions of installing Cython, PyProj on Linux platform, @martinfleis?

Comment: I have just tried `pip install pyproj` in a clean Ubuntu environment (without Cython) and it works without an issue. Make sure you have the recent `pip`.